# Coq: unfold all Definitions

Tags: coq, definition, coq-tactic

Is there a tactic for unfolding all `Definition`s (in the goal, optionally also in hypotheses)? Something shorter than `unfold def, def0, ... in *.`

Comment: I am not sure if tactics such as `cbn / cbv` can do this. You should be able to tell them to only apply to `unfold` reduction rule.

Comment: @ejgallego  Indeed, `cbv in *` does the job. Since [coq.inria.fr](https://coq.inria.fr/) is down, I cannot look for its options to do unfold only. You might make this into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cbv delta in *` for example.

See https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html?highlight=cbv#coq:tacn.cbv